# what is the meaning of "Veg" word in shorty words?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In English Science Fiction movie [Paycheck (2003)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paycheck_(film)), *Shorty* performs experiment on Michael's memory using some sci-fi equipment. So *Shorty* warns surrounding people about experiment by saying this lines.

> If this man's brain temp goes one C above 43, he's a **veg**.

so what is the meaning of "Veg" word in shorty words?

Comment: You can find the word in all dictionaries : [veg](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/veg#Noun).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's short for *vegetable*:

> [vegetable](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/vegetable)
>   *Informal.* a person who is so severely impaired mentally or physically as to be largely incapable of conscious responses or activity.
>   (Dictionary.com)

So he's warning everyone that Michael might suffer sever brain damage.